# Updating Collection View Number of Items based on selected table view row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

Basically, in my project I have a `collection view` within a `table view` cell, it all works **fine** apart from trying to detect the **number of items** needed for the `collection view` which will vary based on what `table view` row they selected.

The `collection view` works fine if I set a fixed valued for the `numberOfItemsInSection`, but that value would only work for `1 table view cell`. I've stored the string value of the selected table view row and try to pass it to my `custom table view cell` which contains the `collection view` so it can update but it always returns `nil`.

Any ideas on how to get it to automatically updated based on the selected table view row?

Below is my code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


        return categoryItems.count // THIS IS WHERE I GET AN ERROR
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        //
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell
        //What is this CustomCollectionCell? Create a CustomCell with SubClass of UICollectionViewCell
        //Load images w.r.t IndexPath
        print(self.selectedCategory.description)
        let newArray = starbucksMenu[selectedCategory]
        //cell.image.image = UIImage(named: (allItems[selectedCategory]?[indexPath.row])!)
        cell.label.text = categoryItems[indexPath.row]
        //cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.1




        return cell
```

That is my Collection View Code.

Below is the Table View Delegate function that sets the values:

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(indexPath.row)
        word = indexPath.row
        guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? ExpandableCell
            else { return }

        switch cell.isExpanded
        {
        case true:
            self.expandedRows.remove(indexPath.row)

        case false:
            self.expandedRows.insert(indexPath.row)

        }



        self.selectedCategory = categories[indexPath.row]
        print(self.selectedCategory)
        cell.selectedCategory = selectedCategory
        //self.array = starbucksMenu[starbucksMenuCategories[indexPath.row]]!
        //self.collectionView.reloadData()
        cell.menuItems = allItems[selectedCategory]!
        cell.categoryItems = allItems[selectedCategory]!
        cell.isExpanded = !cell.isExpanded
        self.itemsArray = allItems[selectedCategory]!
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.endUpdates()




        }
```

Comment: you need to reload collection view also while exapnd.

Comment: I tried collectionView.reloadData() but it always crashes and returns nil. Is there a different way of doing it?